# Efficiently transforming values inside a delimited string

Tags: apex, string, performance

I have a String **extDB_Table__c.inputString__c** that looks like this:

```
MTHS|||ECON|||SPN|||
```

The `|||` is meant to be a delimiter between whatever values are in the string *(comes after every value, including the final one)*.

Values like `SPN` are all keys in a `Map<String,String>` **transMap**, where the values are translations to the equivalent spelling of the concept in a multi-select picklist, e.g.

```
ECON --> Economics
MTHS --> Math and Statistics
SPN --> Spanish
THE --> Theology
```

Sometimes I'll have another string **Opportunity.MSP__c** with a pre-existing value like `Dance;Economics;Astronomy`

**I'd like to optimize two different operations:**

1. Building a semicolon-delimited string **outputStringA** full of the "translated" values like `Math and Statistics;Economics;Spanish` *(when I know there's no Opportunity related to the extDB_Table__c record I'm processing and I have to create it)*
2. Building a semicolon-delimited string **outputStringB** that takes **Opportunity.MSP__c** into account and produces something like `Dance;Economics;Astronomy;Math and Statistics;Spanish` *(order and redundancy of `Economics` not important as long it's not important when doing DML to multi-select picklists)*

What Apex algorithms / code patterns would people suggest for building **outputStringA** and for building **outputStringB** as efficiently as possible?  *(I can think of a lot of ways to do it inefficiently...)*

This is inside a loop through **extDB_Table__c** records.  The delimiter pattern for **extDB_Table__c.inputString__c** is always the same; there is a branch inside the loop to determine whether I need to compute **outputStringA** or **outputStringB**.

Comment: No need to add Apex in the title. It's redundant, that's what tags are for and it's pretty clear in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with multi-picklist fields, I've generally found the most sensible thing is to `Split` them into collections, then `Join` them once you've added all the members you want.  I've made a few assumptions about the context of your situation.

```
public static void mergePicklist(extDB_Table__c tab, Opportunity opp)
{
    //Zero in the limit parameter removes trailing empty strings according to the documentation
    List<String> inputStringList = tab.InputString__c.Split('\\|\\|\\|', 0);
    Set<String> finalSet = new Set<String>();
    if (opp.MSP__c != null)
    {
        finalSet.addAll(opp.MSP__c.split(';'));
    }
    for(String input : inputStringList)
    {
        finalSet.add(transMap.get(input));
    }
    opp.MSP__c = String.join(new List<String>(finalSet), ';');
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @IllusiveBrian -- that is exactly what I'm talking about as far as functionality is concerned (I suppose I should have included something like this in my original question, so thank you).  Leaving the question open for others' thoughts on performance optimization, though.  Particularly in the outputStringA example, I keep wondering if there's an efficient way to treat extDB_Table__c.inputString__c as some sort of buffer--working from left to right through the string, replacing pieces directly as they're detected and then moving on.

Comment: Working from your example:  since i'll have separate code blocks handling cases when Opportunity exists or not, in the outputStringA case do you think it'd be any more efficient to do a traditional for loop to `i<inputStringList.size()`, do `inputStringList[i]=transMap.get(inputStringList[i])`, and join inputStringList itself after the loop?

Comment: You might want to make sure you remove `null` or the empty string as there is a terminating delimiter.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think setting the limit parameter to 0 should remove the last blank trailing string based on what the documentation for split says: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm, however I just noticed that overload when I was writing this answer so I've never tried it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - I just split this 'fred;wilson;' and the size of the resultant lit was 2. Seems SF automatically throws away the empty part. The Limit parameter limits to total size of the split. if 0, nothing different happens, it is default, if 1 the result is 'fred;wilson;', if 2 the result is 'fred, wilson;' if 3 'fred,wilson, ' if 0 or null 'fred,wilson'

Comment: @k.. Strings are immutable, so you can't really use it the way you are suggesting.  Even if they weren't, they are usually an array "under the hood" so adding characters in the middle means you have to push every character afterward further back.  The problem with trying to figure out how to optimize a solution is that we need to know more about your expected data - if you have many duplicates, adding them to the set doesn't do anything, so the final join is against fewer elements.  If you don't have many duplicates, your solution may be more efficient.  Do you need a particular optimization?

Comment: @IllusiveBrian -- good point!  (String immutability & array-moving.)  Thanks for the insights.  No particular optimization needed -- I just didn't want to be wasting memory & CPU time, since I knew this would be running inside a loop processing data-loads of many records at a time.